# Why "return" is returning 'None' instead the of required 'List'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm writing a code that returns the elements on `odd positions` in that list. When I run my program, it's showing no output. But when I replace `return lst2` with `return print(lst2)` it's showing me the required output.
So my question is why my program is not showing any output when I write `return lst2`?

```
def op(lst):
    lst2=[]

    for i in lst:
        indx=lst.index(i)

        if indx%2==1:
            lst2.append(i)

    return lst2

a=[22, 5, 7, 35, 1, 100, 15]
op(a)
```

Comment: This code does not have any `print()` statements.  Why are you expecting something to be printed?  "return" does not mean "also print".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. @JohnGordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not printing the list, you are just returning it (**the list object itself**). This `op(a)` is appropriate if you want to do something with the list, but if you just want to print its content you should call `print(op(a))` or change the **op** function to print the contents of the list instead of returning it.

Answer (score 2):

You are just returning the list, not printing it.

```
def op(lst):
    lst2 = []

    for i in lst:
        indx = lst.index(i)

        if indx % 2 == 1:
            lst2.append(i)

    return lst2


a = [22, 5, 7, 35, 1, 100, 15]
print(op(a))
```

Comment: 'return' returns the value so why it's not returning the list?

Comment: It actually is returning the list, you are just not doing anything with the return value.: `print(type(op(a)))`

Comment: @Aetooc Right. `return` returns an object to the code that called the function. It does not print anything to the screen.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. @Leemosh

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. @PaulM.